# getting the alt value in the div tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to get the value "4" from below html from this [website](https://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-walking-shoes/7puZ9ypZoi3). This is just one of the values from the product list page. I want multiple values in a list form to put it in a dataframe.

```
<div class="review-stars-on-hover">
<divclass="product-rating">
<divclass="product-rating__meter"alt="4">
<divclass="product-rating__meter-btm">★★★★★</div>
<divclass="product-rating__meter-top"style="width:80%;">★★★★★</div>
</div>
<divclass="product-rating__countedf-font-size--xsmallnsg-text--medium-grey"alt="95">(95)</div>
</div>
</div>...
```

I tried:

```
items = soup.select('.grid-item-content')
star = [item.find('div', {'class': 'review-stars-on-hover'}).get('alt') for item in items]
```

Output(there are 16 products in total in the page, but only none shows up):

`[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]`

Any advice please?

Comment: There is no `grid-item-content` in your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.However it returns 16 records based on the class you have mentioned but its only having 11 records for the class `product-rating__meter`.I have provided the check if `product-rating__meter` class available then print the `alt` value.
Hope this will help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
data= requests.get('https://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-walking-shoes/7puZ9ypZoi3').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
print("Total element count : " + str(len(soup.find_all('div',class_='grid-item-content'))))
for item in soup.find_all('div',class_='grid-item-content'):
    if item.find('div',class_='product-rating__meter'):
        print("Alt value : " + item.find('div',class_='product-rating__meter')['alt'])
```

Output

---

```
Total element count : 16
```

---

```
Alt value : 4
Alt value : 4.3
Alt value : 4.6
Alt value : 4.8
Alt value : 4.4
Alt value : 4.7
Alt value : 4.7
Alt value : 3.8
Alt value : 4.5
Alt value : 3.3
Alt value : 4.5
```

**EDITED**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
data= requests.get('https://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-walking-shoes/7puZ9ypZoi3').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
print("Total element count : " + str(len(soup.find_all('div',class_='grid-item-content'))))
itemlist=[]
for item in soup.find_all('div',class_='grid-item-content'):
    if item.find('div',class_='product-rating__meter'):
        #print("Alt value : " + item.find('div',class_='product-rating__meter')['alt'])
        itemlist.append("Alt value : " + item.find('div',class_='product-rating__meter')['alt'])
print(itemlist)
```

OutPut:

```
Total element count : 16
['Alt value : 4', 'Alt value : 4.3', 'Alt value : 4.6', 'Alt value : 4.8', 'Alt value : 4.4', 'Alt value : 4.7', 'Alt value : 4.7', 'Alt value : 3.8', 'Alt value : 4.5', 'Alt value : 3.3', 'Alt value : 4.5']
```

Comment: really appreciate but can I have those list looking like this? `[Alt value : 4,Alt value : 4.3,Alt value : 4.6,Alt value : 4.8,Alt value : 4.4,Alt value : 4.7,Alt value : 4.7,Alt value : 3.8,Alt value : 4.5,Alt value : 3.3,Alt value : 4.5]`

Comment: Declare an empty list before for loop like itemlist=[]  and append the print item like itemlist.append(—printvalue-) I have posted earlier. Then print the itemlist at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can select by taking the first match only for inner class within parent class

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-walking-shoes/7puZ9ypZoi3')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
stars = [item.select_one('.product-rating__meter')['alt']  for item in soup.select('.grid-item-box:has(.product-rating__meter)')]
```

Comment: thank you but I need a list of values and not only one value. Im expecting 16 values but only "none" is extracted

Comment: this gives me a record of -> `['4', '4', '4.3', '4.3', '4.6', '4.6', '4.8', '4.8', '4.4', '4.4', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '3.8', '3.8', '4.5', '4.5', '3.3', '3.3', '4.5', '4.5']` However, there are duplicates. For example the first '4' & '4' is the star rate for the first product. I just want one '4'

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like below to retrieve all divs with "alt" attribute:

```
xml = bs.find_all("div", {"alt": True})
```

And to retrieve the value:

```
for x in xml:
    print(x["alt"])
```

Or directly like below if you only want the first "alt":

```
xml = bs.find("div", {"alt": True})["alt"]
```

Comment: I tried one of your solution. Can you please check my question again. Your first solution is working but gives me not only the numbers but other elements as well.I only need the alt values for stars such as 4, 4.3, 4.6...